# Setting a product to in-stock raises foreign key exception

Tags: database

When executing the following:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$stock_item = $product->getStockItem();
$stock_item->setIsInStock(true);
$stock_item->save();
//...other product edits...
$product->save();
```

For a very small amount of products (~13 or so) in the store (~10k SKUs) the following exception is raised:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON DE...
```

Again, this is a very small number of items many of which are defunct. There have been no manual db edits, but, I'm curious if there are others that have this issue that I don't/won't know about. Is there a way to handle this or to rectify this at the db level?

Comment: Did you import your products automatically?

This error is interessting. What (I think) happens is, that the stock-model is not loaded, normally you only have one stock (1, Default) and the product-ID is known.

This stock item already exists. The question is: is it loaded with the model? And if yes, why is the ID not used for an update rather for an insert? If no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately fixed this by using Magento's own db cleanup tool, which identified foreign key errors and corrected; though it did not identify causality.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Comment: That almost never works. **Result!**

Comment: I am living proof that it did! Crazy!

Answer (score 3):

I found that you sometimes need to initialise the stock item, otherwise I would get the Integrity constraint violation when I tried to save the product.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
if($stockItem && !$stockItem->getProductId()) { // CHECK STOCK ITEM IS INITIALISED
    $stockItem->setData('product_id', $productId);
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
}

$stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 5);
$stockItem->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past when importing stock and product information I have created a separate script for products and stock. I have been successful in updating the stock information and calling save on the stock item and then continuing to work with the product.

```
$oProduct->load($aProductInformation['id']);
$oStockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$oStockItem->assignProduct($oProduct);
$oStockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$oStockItem->save();
```

The assignProduct function seems to validate if the product has a stock item already assigned and will preform an update in this case.

Comment: Correct - I mis-typed above. See updated answer.

Comment: +1 - you correctly state that saving a stock item requires calling save on the stock object itself; though, this did not resolve my actual issue which is finding broken foreign keys in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that magento was inserting '107677-1-1' in item_id which is an integer field, and it truncates values after '-', hence it finds duplicate, any idea how to stop it?